# How to set ui minimal view in safari in ios with brim

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, viewport

I am using brim to set a minimal-ui view in safari of iPhone 6 S.

I want to enter into minimal-ui view mode when swiping up the page, but the only way to do that is to rotate the screen. My page doesn't have offset to do a scroll.

I am searching in the library a method to have the minimal view on the screen, but I don't find it.

https://github.com/gajus/brim

Comment: I'm pretty sure Safari/iOS removed the api to force minimal view.

Comment: It's still possilble to the user to go minimal-ui without the api.

Comment: Of course it is. But you as a developer can't manipulate it anymore.

Comment: I think I shall use this library only to detect if it is in minimal view. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems not possible to enter in minimal-u view calling some javascript method because safari doesn't allow it. The alternative solution to enter this mode is to inform the user to do some action like swipe up or rotate the device.